# Integrals and Dirac delta measures

Tags: measure-theory

Why is it the case that in general $\int X d\delta_k(w) = X(k) $?? 
I can't seem to work it out but it seems like a useful fact?

Comment: This is the defining property of the Dirac delta.

Comment: Should the right-hand side be $X(0)$? Or at what point is that dirac measure standing on?

Comment: Yes, thankyou I have changed it and I think it is correct now? Can anybody explain why this is the case or is it just by definition?

Comment: Yeah, it looks correct now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's two methods of how to show it. Someone correct me if I made some mistakes.

**Method 1.** It can be proven in steps, starting from simple functions and moving on to measurable functions. (Note that since the whole powerset is the collection of $\delta_{k}$-measurable sets, then every function is $\delta_{k}$-measurable.)

Assume first that $X$ is a simple function, and let $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\chi_{A_{i}}$ be its normal representation. Then
\begin{align*}
\int X\,d\delta_{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\int \chi_{A_{i}}\,d\delta_{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\delta_{k}(A_{i})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\chi_{A_{i}}(k)=X(k),
\end{align*}
since $\delta_{k}(A_{i})=1$ if $k\in A_{i}$ and $0$ otherwise, which is indeed the same as the indicator function of $A_{i}$ at point $k$ (which is indeed the key point to notice).

Assume then that $X$ is non-negative and measurable. There now exists a nondecreasing sequence of simple functions $(\psi_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ so that $\psi_{i}\to X$ pointwise. Using the monotone convergence theorem $(*)$ and the previous step $(**)$ we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\int X\,d\delta_{k} &=\int \lim_{i\to\infty}\psi_{i}\,d\delta_{k}\overset{(*)}{=}\lim_{i\to\infty}\int \psi_{i}\,d\delta_{k}\overset{(**)}{=}\lim_{i\to\infty} \psi_{i}(k)=X(k).
\end{align*}

The result then finally follows by composing any measurable function $X$ to $X=X^{+}-X^{-}$ and invoking the previous step to both of them.

**Method 2:** Use the fact that for $\delta_{k}$-a.e. we have $X=X(k)$ and integrate.

Comment: Thanks very much that's really helpful, I think method 1 is more in line with my course, could you just explain to me though you have written  "The result then finally follows by composing any measurable function X  to X=X + −X −   and invoking the previous step to both of them". Does this mean that both X+ and X- are integrable? Im a little confused

Comment: @rosie: We can always do such a composition $X=X^{+}-X^{-}$ where $X^{+}=\max\{X,0\}$ and $X^{-}=-\min\{X,0\}$. Then by using the previous step (since both $X^{+}$ and $X^{-}$ are non-negative and measurable) we get $\int X\,d\delta_{k}=\int X^{+}\,d\delta_{k}-\int X^{-}\,d\delta_{k}=X^{+}(k)-X^{-}(k)=X(k)$.